# Relationship IN and OUT not working as expected with cypher in graphql/neo4j

Tags: neo4j, graphql, grandstack

I'm having an issue creating a relationship the right way, I have these schemas :

```
type User {
  id: ID!
  mail: String!
  password: String! @private
  meals: [Meal] @relationship(type: "IN_MEALS", direction: IN)
}

type Meal {
  name: String!
  createdBy: User! @relationship(type: "IN_MEALS", direction: OUT)
}
```

And I added this mutation to create a meal directly as one of the current user's like so :

```
type Mutation {
  createMeal(name: String!): Meal
    @cypher(
      statement: """
      MATCH (u:User {id: $auth.jwt.id})
      MERGE (m:Meal {name: $name})-[r:IN_MEALS]->(u)
      RETURN m
      """
    )
}
```

In neo4j databse the relation is made to the user and all seems good but when I query meals of the users or the createdBy field of a meal it shows "null", what am I missing?

Comment: Does the Meal get created ?

Comment: Yes meal is created and in the neo4j database the link is created between user and meal

The problem is when I do a graphql query, the user has no "meals" and the meal has no "createdBy"